# Optimizing query with multiple sums?

Tags: sql, hive, rollup, grouping-sets

I have table `products`:

```
+----------+-----------+----------+---------+
|family_id |shopper_id |product_id|quantity |
+----------+-----------+----------+---------+
|A         |1          |Kit Kat   |10       |
|A         |1          |Kit Kat   |5        |
|A         |1          |Snickers  |9        |
|A         |2          |Kit Kat   |7        |
|B         |3          |Kit Kat   |2        |
+----------+---------- +----------+---------+
```

For each product, I want to calculate 2 totals:

- total quantity per shopper
- total quantity per family. Sum of total quantities for all shoppers in the same family.

The final table should look like:

```
+----------+----------+-------------------------+-----------------------+
|shopper_id|product_id|total_quantity_shopper   |total_quantity_family  |
+----------+----------+-------------------------+-----------------------+
|1         |Kit Kat   | 15                      | 22                    |
|1         |Snickers  | 9                       | 9                     |
|2         |Kit Kat   | 7                       | 22                    |
|3         |Kit Kat   | 2                       | 2                     |
+----------+----------+-------------------------|-----------------------|
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT
    distinct shopper_id,
    product_id,
    sum(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY shopper_id, product_id) as total_quantity_shopper,
    sum(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY family_id, product_id) as total_quantity_family
FROM
    products;
```

But looking at the query plan, it looks very inefficient (I think). How can I improve the query above?

Comment: hi, interesting does group by perform any differently?

Comment: @IronMan, can you show an example?

Comment: Family is not a key on each row, so I'm not really clear on what the columns mean.

Comment: A family consists of one or more shoppers. A `shopper_id` is unique across all families.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the family is a hierarchy for the shopper.  So, I would suggest `group by` and window functions:

```
select family_id, shopper_id, product_id,
       sum(quantity) as total_quantity_shopper,
       sum(sum(quantity)) over (partition by family_id, product_id) as total_quantity_family
from products
group by family_id, shopper_id, product_id
```

Comment: Getting this error: `Failed to breakup Windowing invocations into Groups. At least 1 group must only depend on input columns. Also check for circular dependencies. Underlying error: ...Expression not in GROUP BY key 'quantity' `

Comment: @alhazen . . . Oops.  I missed a `sum()` in that syntax.

Comment: beautiful, @GordonLinoff . I just found out that, at least in PostgreSQL and Vertica (I have no access to a hive database) , you can even omit `family_id` from the column list, while still grouping by it ....

Comment: @marcothesane . . . You can actually remove `family_id` from `select` in any database.  But I think the results make more sense if it is there.